# Comparing two models at AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Let's say I have these models

firstGoals

```
{
  GoalId: 30
  GoalDesc: "The quick brown fox"
},
{
  GoalId: 31
  GoalDesc: "The quick brown fox junior"
},{
  GoalId: 32
  GoalDesc: "The quick brown fox senior"
}
```

secondGoals

```
{
  GoalId: 30
  GoalDesc: "The quick brown fox"
},
{
  GoalId: 35
  GoalDesc: "The big bad fox"
},{
  GoalId: 36
  GoalDesc: "The little red fox"
}
```

these are my htmls:

```
<table>
       <tr ng-repeat="goal in firstGoals" id="choose-goals-row-{{goal.GoalId}}">
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="selection-chkbox-{{goal.GoalId}}" ng-model="secondaryGoals[$index].selected" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" style="float:left;margin-left:0px;"/></td>
            <td>{{goal.GoalDesc}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<table>
       <tr ng-repeat="goal in secondGoals" id="choose-goals-row-{{goal.GoalId}}">
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="selection-chkbox-{{goal.GoalId}}" ng-model="secondaryGoals[$index].selected" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" style="float:left;margin-left:0px;"/></td>
            <td>{{goal.GoalDesc}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

How can I compare those two models using filtering? I need the first model "firstGoals" objects not existing at the second model "secondGoals" using jQuery and AngularJS via their GoalId property?

firstGoals should be live or observable(I'm using the latest library of AngularJS)
What I'm doing right now is that, If i clicked the remove button, the goals I selected in the **firstGoals** model will be transferred(push and splice method) to **secondGoals** and vice-versa for removing this is bulk add/remove of objects/array.

Additional: All that should be displayed at **firstGoals** should be non-existent at **secondGoals** given that we are splicing and pushing bulk objects in that same format.. I was thinking of the **firstGoals** model should be in auto-refresh

Comment: Maybe just try to create a custom filter? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: That's what I need. However I don't know.:(

Answer (score 0):

I guess both first and second goals models are arrays. 
When pushing into secondGoals just check whether the data is already is present in secondGoals (`secondgoals.indexOf(data)==-1`), if not push it. Same is applicable to firstGoals as well

```
scope.pushData = function(from, to, data){
  if(to.indexOf(data) == -1){
    to.push(data);
  }
  from.splice(from.indexOf(data),1);
}

<div ng-click='pushData(firstGoals, secondGoals, data)></div>
```

Comment: Are you adding/removing multiple object one by one or as a bulk. Either way you can include the add/remove option inside the ng-repeat if you are doing it one by one or incase of bulk loop through the objects which has to be added or removed and invoke the pushData function.
Can you provide a sample plunker code on how you want it to be?